# prevent eval of a single src block

Tags: org-babel

How do I ensure that only the second block never evaluates, while still allowing the first block to be evaluated normally?

```
#+begin_src shell
echo "hi"
#+end_src

#+begin_src python
print("no print please")
#+end_src
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `:eval no` attribute on the block that you want to disable:

```
#+begin_src shell
echo "hi"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: hi

#+begin_src python :eval no
print("no print please")
#+end_src
```

Comment: perfect, thanks!